# Equal height columns w/ footer using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a business application that has a variable width sidebar and content area, along with a footer.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to make the footer ALWAYS display correctly using CSS, regardless of sidebar height.  Here's an illustration of the issue:

[image]

The footer and sidebar is fine if the content area is larger than the sidebar, but not the reverse (the [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique doesn't seem to work with a footer, and the [equal height with footer](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61) technique only seemed to work if the sidebar is shorter).

Any suggestions?  I found an answer here that only worked for IE6, but nothing else just using CSS.  I'm tempted to make my life easy and use TABLEs, but either way I'd love to know how to do this w/ CSS (a little javascript wouldn't hurt, but w/o is better).

Comment: Can you post your css? What you're attempting is very possible, but there may be something missing from your styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One technique is to use a very large value for the columns' `padding-bottom` and a similarly large *negative* value for `margin-bottom`.  Something like the following:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container .column {
    padding-bottom: 20010px;  /* X + padding-bottom */
    margin-bottom: -20000px;  /* X */
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
}
```

The best description of the method I've seen is the in the ["One True Layout"](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight) article on [Position is Everything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/).  (Don't forget to check out the [potential problems](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/appendix/equalheightproblems) article as well.)

Comment: We posted the same link within 20 secs of eachother.  Deleting and upvoting yours ;)

Comment: Originally we tried this and it didn't work (if the sidebar was shorter than the content area it would show an empty space).  As a work-around, I removed my sidebar's background and set the body's background to what the sidebar should be ... it's now "good enough".

Answer (score 1):

If you have both Sidebar and MainContent floated then putting `clear: both;` in the rules for the footer should mean it always gets pushed down - [see this two column layout tutorial on 456 Berea Street](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/) for more details.  If your Sidebar is absolutely positioned then you could be having a bit more fun, [here's a good resource for other layouts](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=TwoColumnLayouts).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to this that i foind was using some JS to calculate the heights of the sidebar, and content areas and then making them both equal. calling the JS function onload. If you can find a better solution let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) might be what you're looking for. I worked with a similar layout to yours and I used this solution, with a few modifications, to get it to obey not just the content height, but also the sidebar height.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another option - it is cross browser and without any hacks - check [equal height columns](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)